# Increase generation of numbers inside loop (SQL, Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, math, plsql

I had generate 1 round numbers:

```
set serveroutput on
declare 
i number(9);
x number(9) := 0;
begin
 for i in 0..7 loop   
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x);
  x:=x+1;
 end loop;
end;
```

Result is: 0, 1, 2, 3....7

My next round should generate numbers: 10, 11, 12....17

Total output should looks as below:

```
0    1    2    3    4    5    6   7
10   11   12   13   14   15   16  17
20   21   22   23   24   25   26  27
...
80   81   82   83   84   85   86  87
```

How can I jump 3 between each round? I will increase my counter till 81.

Comment: Hint:  `x := x + 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set serveroutput on
declare 
i number(9);
y number(9);
x number(9) := 0;
z number(9) := 0;
begin
 for y in 0..8 loop
   for i in 0..7 loop   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x);
    x := z+i+1;
   end loop;
   z := z + 10;
   x := z;
 end loop; 
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to output 9 times 7 numbers. That is one loop running 9 times and inside a loop that runs 7 times, I'd say. E.g.

```
begin
 for i in 0..8 loop   
   for j in 0..7 loop   
     dbms_output.put(i * 10 + j);
     dbms_output.put(' ');
   end loop;
   dbms_output.put_line('');
 end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about such a `WHILE` loop?

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2     i   number := 0;
  3  begin
  4     while i < 30
  5     loop
  6        dbms_output.put_line (i);
  7
  8        i := i + case when substr (to_char (i), -1) >= 7 then 3 else 1 end;
  9     end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Logic is: if i mod 10 = 7 then increment by 3 otherwise increment by one. Thus,

```
set serveroutput on
declare 
i number(9);
x number(9) := 0;
begin
 for i in 0..100 loop   
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x);
  IF mod(i,10) = 7  THEN
    x := x +3;
  ELSE
    x:=x+1;
  END IF;
 end loop;
end;
```

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following

Comment: fixed  sorry about that